# Why do KVO observers see an empty NSKeyValueChangeNewKey when observing an unordered to-many relationship?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

There is a property on a `UIViewController` subclass that changes when a view becomes visible. (A set stops being empty.) I've implemented KVC/KVO as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"anticipatedIndexPaths" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueSetSetMutation usingObjects:_anticipatedIndexPaths];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    assert([_anticipatedIndexPaths count]);
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"anticipatedIndexPaths" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueSetSetMutation usingObjects:_anticipatedIndexPaths];
}
```

A subclass of that class is observing itself for `@"anticipatedIndexPaths"`, but the value of `NSKeyValueChangeNewKey` when observing `NSKeyValueChangeReplacement` is always an empty set. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Two things:

First, at least for unordered to-many relationships, the KVO infrastrucure records the value of your property on the `willChange-:` call. On `didChange-:`, it passes only the given set *minus* the previous value. Second, on `viewWillAppear:`, even before the `[super viewWillAppear:]` call, `hidden == NO`.

In my case, this meant by property was returning the non-empty set. The result of KVO's subtraction was the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `addObserver:...`, are you passing `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` as an option? You don't get this value by default.

Comment: Good thought, but yeah, I am.  `[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"anticipatedIndexPaths" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld|NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];`